# How to add class files to a Gradle source set from a standalone plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am writing a Gradle plugin and I need to tell the Java plugin that my plugin also creates class files (from wasm, which the Java compiler can't do).

I've put the class files at `$buildDir/classes/wasm/main`.

I need the classes in this directory to be put in the resulting jar created by the jar task.

I can do this in the `build.gradle` file easily enough:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "build/classes/wasm/main"
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to do this from the plugin code so that users don't need to copy this on every build file.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

A small detail: I made the class files visible to the Java code (so the IDE can also see the generated classes) by making this directory a dependency of the Java project:

```
project.dependencies.add("implementation", project.files(compileWasm.outputDir))
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it either, and whether these two problems are actually related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do the same thing as I was doing in the build file...

Using Kotlin syntax:

```
val sourceSet = project.extensions.getByType(SourceSetContainer::class.java)
sourceSet.getByName("main").resources.srcDir(compileWasm.outputDir)
```

This solves the problem, but I would be very interested in knowing if the way I am doing this is as you would expect in this situation (i.e. "enriching" the output of the Java plugin with more classes).